# Best practices to ease the OS upgrade procedure

Tags: upgrade, lts

I'm going to install a fresh Ubuntu (LTS). My question is about the upgrade to the new LTS version, and in particular I'd like to know which best practices I have to adopt to reduce potential upgrade issues when the new version is released.

For example, don't install packages from unofficial repositories, etc.

I'll appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice I can think of is take measures so that, in case of any problem, you can go back to your old configuration while you work on fixing the problem.

In particular:

- Backup your data
- Keep your data in a different partition than the OS
- Reserve a spare partition for the future distribution

The last bullet I think isn't very common, but I find it quite effective. What I do when I have to upgrade is avoid the upgrade procedure completely and just install the new distribution in a different partition while using the same partition for my home directory. This way, if the new distribution doesn't work for me, I can either look into the problem and try to fix it or, if I need to do some other thing, use the old distribution.

I've never had any serious problem; but, at the same time, I've always been sure that in case of any problem (drivers, configuration, etc.), I could go back and use my old stable configuration as usual without any danger to my personal files.

Comment: This answer is still valid and not version specific.