# Do you wait for a release upgrade to stabilise before going ahead with it?

Tags: upgrade, system

I'm new to ubuntu/debian being a gentoo user for many years, so please excuse my ignorance.

I've just been informed of the release of 12.04 but when I review the package list I noticed an inconsistency. The Groovy language and groovy-doc is no longer supported by canonical and will be removed. However groovy-doc will also be upgraded.

I only realise this because it's something of interest to me so I wouldn't have any idea about all the other areas of the system I don't know anything about.

I feel I should wait some time for the release to have some problems ironed out before I continue with the upgrade. Is that a advised practice?

Comment: Just [spotted this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43955/best-practices-to-ease-the-os-upgrade-procedure)

Comment: strangely working ok now! Hey people would be really nice if I could have just one or two votes because I can't even vote up answers let alone comments on here yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11.10 has just now been released, 12.04 is the planned one that is still being discussed (ie codename only came out a few days ago). You can not test 12.04 (should not, really).

If you are looking for pure stability use the [LTS Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), if you want edge but without many issues use the current one -1, so use 11.04 for now. After a couple of weeks you can safely upgrade to the current one, 11.10. Not that it is not safe to install it now but there might be some edges that need perfection as you can understand.

There is a release of Ubuntu every 6 months, in April and in October, the versions start with the year+release month, ie: current one is 11.10, released in 2011, in October.

There is a release of Ubuntu LTS every 2 years with support for over 3 years, previous one was 10.04 and has support until 2013, next one will be 12.04.

Comment: Indeed, I've realised that there is something strange going on when I did some googling and found the release schedule. I cancelled the upgrade and tried to do a normal upadte, it tells me that 11.10 is available but when I ask it to go ahead then it tells me it's going to 12.04 . I wonder what is going on! Thanks for the information regarding releases!

Comment: Its really weird that its telling you that the release is telling you 12.04! If you are just updating from 11.04 it should say 11.10. Did you enable any developer repos or something weird?

Comment: Mark the question as answered if that satisfies it. glad it helped.

Comment: I haven't got many repositories, only a couple of google/debian ones and I took out the UK mirrors and the extras one, didn't effect the result. It says 11.10 first, then when you click upgrade the title is 12.04. I've check my /etc/apt/sources.list and can't see anything weird there

Comment: I would say its just a glitch but you never know, you can also try to run `update-manager –d` at the console after you did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: god damn I was just about to post a comment about how very repeatable the glitch was, started taking some screenshots of the update manager and guess what happened, it didn't repeat itself. Perhaps something was updated today to make the change but now it does indeed follow through with the 11.10 upgrade. Although it does complain about skype and bomb out

Comment: Yeah, thats normal, skype has to be reinstalled and will work perfectly, dont worry ;)

Comment: Got you some rep up, gl and if you need ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must not upgrade to Precise Pangolin (12.04) unless you are going to develop it. Its development just started a few days ago, so it's *extremely* unstable. 11.10 is released, but as we all know, some bugs aren't discovered until after release, so if you're not in a hurry, you may choose to delay upgrade to 11.10. 11.04 is supported until October next year, so it's no rush.

I've been using 11.10 for about six weeks, and it's come along nicely. There are a few issues still, though, particularly with regards to multiple screens. But all in all, it's good. I think newcomers to GNU/Linux should be recommended to use 10.04LTS, or wait for 12.04. With all the great changes going on, Ubuntu isn't as stable and polished as it usually is.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside for now the obsolete versions mentioned here.

For stability it's recommended to wait for the first [point release](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) prior to upgrading.